# in mysql i want to make select that will show everything between 2dates

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have datetime in my table like this 01.08.2012 14:20 22.10.2012 10:02

i enter 2 dates(can i enter them just as 10.08.2012 or i have to add time to ) and i want to do this

```
 $sqlSelectMY='BDate >= "'.$fromDate.'" AND BDate <="'.$toDate.'"';

 "SELECT* FROM table  WHERE ".$sqlSelectMY.";";
```

I put the date clause in variable sqlSelectMy and than use it in the variable that i call the select from the mysql database i would like to see some examples if anyone can refer any to me thx. How to write the input dates that will do the thing that i need now with the code there is even if I input dates like i have at the top with time it doesnt do anything...

Comment: how to fix this because it doesnt make any result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use phps function substr()  to fix the date format to be YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS and use that variable for fromDate and toDate variables , that should do it , I will edit soon with some working code soon as i write it down :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use this

```
'BDate >= "'.$fromDate.'" AND BDate <="'.$toDate.'"'
```

this will only select fromday upto today - 1 because of the time format;

You can use mysql date function to select datetime accurately

```
 $sqlSelectMY='DATE(BDate) >= "'.$fromDate.'" AND DATE(BDate) <="'.$toDate.'"';
```

this only select base on date of datetime.